# I want to download some audio files from SIM808 to my PC

Tags: esp32, at-command, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32, sim800

need your help
I  am using  SIM808 in a garage door monitoring system. We use the sim808 to answer calls and play audio messages when someone calls the Sim card installed on the SIM808 (the audio files that we play were recorded during a call using AT commands "AT+CREC"). Now We want to download the recorded audio files from the sim808 to a PC and then upload them later to another one (SIM808), I have read the PDF  "SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09" but I was not able to find any AT commands to use for downloading AMR audio files from the SIM808
If any one have done this before: what are the AT commands that I can use to download those files, Can  you please help me with this or is there another method to download and upload audio files to the SIM808
Thank you in advance

Note:
I am using the ESP32 to communicate to the SIM808 (using Rx,Tx ports)

I have tested some AT commands like 'AT+FSCREATE' and 'AT+FSREAD'and others (in the PDF: 'SIM800Series_FS_Application Note_V1.03'), but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to share this answer is case someone needs help with this.
I was able to upload the audio files from the sim808 to my PC using FTP (file Transfer Protocol). Here are the list of AT commands that i have used :

```
AT
AT+CREG?
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","YOUR_Network_APN"         ===> The APN of your network
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+FTPCID=1
AT+FTPSERV="44.241.86.173"                    ===> FTP Server IP address (use the ip address not the link)
AT+FTPUN="dlpuser"                           ===>server user name
AT+FTPPW="rNrKYTX9g7z3RgJRmxWuGHbeu"         ===>server password
AT+FTPPORT=21                                ===>port number (21 default)
AT+FTPTYPE="A"                               ===> 'A' for ASCII, 'I' for Binary 
AT+FTPPUTNAME="2.AMR"                        ===> the name of the file saved to be uploaded to the server            
AT+FTPPUTPATH="/"                            ===> uploading path in the server
AT+FTPFILEPUT=1,"C:\REC\2.AMR"               ===> load the files from the given path to the RAM before uploading it
AT+FTPPUT=1                                  ===> Start  uploading 
AT+FTPFILEPUT=0                              ===> Finish the session
```